# angular js duplicate is not removing in ng-repat

Tags: angularjs

Removing duplicate from ng-repeat :
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/$injector/unpr?p0=uniqueFilterProvider%20%3C-%20uniqueFilter

```
 <script>
    module.filter('unique', function() {
                       return function(collection, keyname) {
                           alert(collection);
                           alert('under the function');
                          var output = [], 
                              keys = [];

                          angular.forEach(collection, function(item) {

                              var key = item[keyname];
                              alert(key);
                              if(keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                                  keys.push(key);

                                  output.push(item);
                              }
                          });
                          alert('output');
                          return output;

                       };
                    });


    </script>
```

Comment: My HTML code:<select ng-model="TechnologyFilter" name="tecN" class="form-control input-sm" ng-change="technologyChange()" required="required">
   <option value="">Select Technology</option>
   <option ng-repeat="technology in technologyName | unique:'technologyName'" value="{{technology.tecName }}"> {{technology.tecName}} </option>
  </select>

Comment: Update your question.

Comment: Check out [Angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#unique).

Answer (score 0):

You might not be correctly registering your filter as a module, so Angular doesn't know it exists. Assuming your Angular app is defined like this

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

Make sure to declare your filter like this:

```
app.filter('unique', function () {
  ...
});
```

Also be sure to include the JavaScript file in which your filter is declared using `<script>` tags in your `index.html`.